# ListField containing pictures and text?

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I want to build an application that has a `ListField`, within which I want to put 12 images and 12 text items. However, I am not familiar with `ListField` -- can anyone help me get started, or provide me with some sample code? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a custom listfield. See the [ListFieldCallback interface](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListFieldCallback.html), and this tutorial:
"[Create a Custom Listfield - Change Highlight Color when Scrolling](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-listfield-change.html)"

Comment: thank q for ur answer ....your given code is ok.i want to display images in table format using list field .so,plz give any code to develop

Comment: Eric's answer provides some good resources that should get you started down the right path.  Have you run into a sticking point that you can't get past?  This is sounding a little like a "give me the code" type request which is generally frowned upon here.

Comment: can u provide me the code for displaying the 7 images on each listfield  row,thank for any help

Comment: Implement the ListFieldCallback interface and every time it gets called you just call the drawBitmap method. You'll have to work it out yourself. It'll be a good learning experience...

Comment: i developed a list field with 12 rows.my problem is when i was scrolling the list field is not scrolling ,the whole list field  is coming on the screen,i want to design my application as it first shows 6 rows,then when i will scroll next rows will come...        VerticalFieldManager _vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(
    Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL |Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR |Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH |Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT  ) {

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // Draw the background image and then call paint.

   }